# Initial command to register existing records in loggable fields

Tags: logging, doctrine-orm, symfony, gedmo-loggable

I'm using Gedmo-Loggable to monitor user activity in loggable entities. It's working just fine but I realized that current values already existing in my database will be lost, when they are overwritten and gedmo loggable save only new value entered to database. 
So I consider two options:

1. Log old value by gedmo-loggable to prevent data lost
2. Use init command to log existing values in my database

I prefer second option, but I have to check all entities for loggable fields, and use protected function CreateLogEntry to create initial logs. This seems not right. Is this approach correct? Does anybody deal with loggable utils?